# Stream the contents of a text file that is being continuously written to.

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu-12.04

So I have a python script which is executed by cron job on a nightly basis to capture data on my data server (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS), this data is being written to a text file. Is there a command to stream what is being written to this file that I would just execute from a shell? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on what exactly you mean by the verb "stream", I think you may be looking for

`tail -f filename`